# Pin tableViews last cell over TabBar and add separator to first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, swift2

I have a question but haven't found any solution for it yet.

How can I pin my TableView with it's last cell over my TabBar 
or at the bottom of the screen if there is no TabBar?

I also want to add a separator over my first cell. The easy way would be to add a view with a height of 1 on top of my tableview but I am searching for a solution to do this by code and use a "real separator".

Here is an example what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: If you *need* to show a picture because it's relevant and will help people answering, just include the link, I'll transform it into a proper picture.

Comment: I added the picture as link. Thank you :)